# Get rid of extra paragraph after table in XSLT

Tags: css, xml, xslt, ms-word

I created a little xsl file for my Word 2010 to Format my bibliography.
Now I created a table and couldn't find out why after each table is a newline or paragraph.
So somewhere in the WWW there was a hint that Word creates an extra paragraph after each table.

How can I get rid of this with XSL?

This is just a test template:

```
  <!--example: [Tag01] Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname: Title (20. April 2014).-->
  <xsl:template match = "b:Source[b:SourceType = 'Book'] | b:Source[b:SourceType = 'Report'] | b:Source[b:SourceType = 'ElectronicSource']">
    <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;width:15%;">    
          <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">
            <span style="font-weight: normal; ">
              <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select = "b:Tag"/>
              <xsl:text>] </xsl:text>
            </span>
          </p>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;width:85%;">    
          <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">
            <!--author-->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="b:Author/b:Author" mode="AuthorNamelistFull" />
            <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
            <!--title-->
            <xsl:value-of select = "b:Title"/>
            <!--date-->
            <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select = "b:City"/>
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select = "b:Year"/>
            <xsl:text>).</xsl:text>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>          
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please add a sample XML (shortened to the relevant point) and the current output result highlighting the part you want to get rid of.

Comment: a CV is best kept in [HR XML](http://www.hr-xml.org/)

Comment: Sorry but I can't add a sample. As I mentioned above I used Microsoft Word 2010 and therefor I created a new style, a xsl-file to layout my bibliography.

Comment: If Word will not create the extra paragraph after each table, then consecutive tables will merge, right?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what you mean. The xsl file runs a Loop to fetch every element that is a e.g. a "book" and creates a table for it. Unfortunately it creates for every record one table instead of putting it into the TD-Tags. So now every created table for the records has an extra paragraph after the closed TABEL-Tag.